# How to take document libraries on the road for use when disconnected

Tags: synchronisation, laptop

My team and I are starting to use a Sharepoint site (2007 if it matters) to keep versions of documents, instead of emailing them back and forth, and having to manually know who has the lastest copy or not.

I am using a laptop, however, and do not always have connectivity.

Is it conveniently possible to keep a mirror of the entire library, latest versions of each file, on my laptop for mobile/disconnected use?

If I make edits on the road, and someone else has edited the same document before I reconnect, I'll deal with the consequences; I'm mostly after a read-only copy for reference purposes, but with the ability to edit and re-sync if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Groove (part of Office 2007) or Microsoft SharePoint Workspace (Office 2010).  Groove became MS Workspace in 2010.  Here is the TechNet overview of SharePoint Workspace: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649102.aspx

Comment: I believe **Workspaces** only work with SharePoint 2010

Comment: I verified on my end and they do not work with 2007 sites, so yes, Groove is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Microsoft Groove 2007 for that.  I seem to recall there are a couple [3rd party vendors](http://www.sharepointreviews.com/product-directory/business-productivity/SharePoint-Products/sharepoint-productivity/sharepoint-offline_c47_m122/) that have off line functionality.